# ¿Como recibir parámetros que provienen de diferentes métodos en un solo método?

Tags: java

Si tenemos en una misma clase el Parametro1 del MetodoA, el Parametro2 del MetodoB, el Parametro3 del MetodoC y el MetodoD ¿Cuál sería la sintaxis necesaria para mandar los parámetros 1, 2 y 3 al método D?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer que tus metodos "regresen" el parametro?
Si puedes hacerlo, basta con invocar el metodoD mandando como parametros "las invocaciones" de los otros metodos.

```
    //Tus funciones asi: 
public static int metodoA(){
    int parametro1 = 0;
    /* Aqui haces otras cosas, supongo */
    return parametro1;
}
    //Los otros metodos parecidos...


public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Al momento de invocar
    metodoD(metodoA(),metodoB(),metodoC());
}
```

Si los metodos A,B y C **no deben regresar nada, o ya regresan otra cosa** la respuesta es un poco mas compleja y larga, primero dime si esto es lo que necesitas, si no, hay mucho que explicar.